# grub PCBSD-GENTOO

Tags: linux, freebsd, grub, gentoo

I have a problem with the configuration of Grub. I installed Gentoo Linux, then I wanted to support PC-BSD, so I created a dedicated extended partition. I just installed PC-BSD on that partition. When you restart the Grub of PC-BSD, it does not detect my Gentoo. What should I do?

I do not think of being able to hand-edit the `grub.cfg`. I can start a live GNU/Linux and use `chroot` to restore the Grub Gentoo and then use proper OS? If you explained to me as well?

Below I give all the relevant details:

`PC-BSD grub.cfg`

[sorry I have to insert external links because I exceed the number of lines allowed]
http://ix.io/1gtf

[image: disk]

Comment: Do you have `os-prober` installed (that's what GRUB uses to figure out OSes on partitions/disks).  And if so what is its output (needs to be run as root, does not take any parameters).

Comment: sorry, I did not understand what you mean , I can not actually access the gentoo linux (if not using chroot ) , I think freebsd ( PC-BSD ) has no chroot , what should I do ? thanks for your answer

Comment: You said you do not plan to hand edit `grub.cfg` therefore  you must be using `grub-mkconfig`, and `grub-mkconfig` uses `os-prober` to find which partitions may have a working OS.  You need to install a bootloader (or use UEFI, but that is  another story) to boot the systems.

Comment: There is currently installed grub on PC-BSD , the problem is that PC-BSD is not available os - prober to make sure to also detect the gentoo grub

Comment: Ehkm... nope.  GRUB is not installed on PC-BSD.  GRUB installs itself on the MBR (or EFI) and then points to partitions.  From whenever you install GRUB (PC-BSD or Gentoo), does this OS (in chroot or not) has `os-prober` installed?  What does it output?

Comment: sisi , I know where you deploy your grub , unfortunately I have a problem to understand what you say because I'm not English , os - prober of PC-BSD is not installed and there is no possibility to install it , then you tell me about chroot gentoo and them to install os - prober and re-install grub ?
many thanks in advance

Comment: ok, I used chroot and installed the grub , now finally gentoo you see , now I just have to add the voice of freebsd to grub